# Issues when installing .exe file generated using Inno on windows xp 64 bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, inno-setup

I have generated an installer(.exe) for 64 bit machine using Inno 5.5.3.
When I try to run the .exe file on my Windows XP 64 bit machine I get the following error message

**"This program does not support the version of Windows your computer is running."**

However when I run the same .exe on my Windows 7 64 bit machine it executes fine and installs the application. I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817932/getting-error-in-installing-setup-with-inno-setup-with-windows-xp-version) but it was unanswered and I couldn't reply to that question(< 50 reputation). Kindly guide me where I am going wrong. And let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using a Windows XP 64 bit machine to generate the installer and want to install on the same machine.

Comment: xp64 was basically a rebadged Server 2003. about the only thing xp64 has in common with xp32 was the name

Answer (score 1):

An installation can run in one of two modes: 32-bit or 64-bit.

64-bit mode is selected if the user is running a 64-bit version of Windows and the system's processor architecture is included in the value of the **ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode** [Setup] section directive. Otherwise, 32-bit mode is used.

There is also [Setup] directive **ArchitecturesAllowed**

Valid values: One or more of the following, separated by spaces: 
*x86 
x64 
ia64*

It specifies which processor architecture(s) Setup is allowed to run on. If this directive is not specified or is blank, Setup will be allowed to run on all processor architectures capable of executing its 32-bit code (including ones it doesn't recognize). Otherwise, if a user's processor architecture is not one of those specified in this directive, Setup will display an error message and exit.

Everything is based on your script (there may be some other directives), so please share your script with us (at least [Setup] section) so we can check it's validity.

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup doesn't generate 64-bit executables. If it's a 64-bit operating system, you need to make sure that the target machine has the 32-bit WoW subsystem installed and enabled .

Comment: Can you tell me the process of installing and enabling 32 bit WoW subsystem?

Comment: I don't have a system where it's been disabled but it should be in the help/MSDN.